# Why does Alys' death make Taverner exist again?

Tags: plot-device, flow-my-tears

In *Flow My Tears, the Policeman Said* by Philip K. Dick, the protagonist (a celebrity named Jason Taverner) spends the majority of the novel in a society where there is no record of his having ever existed, and where nobody recognizes him. Towards the end of the novel, Taverner meets the character Alys Buckman, who both initially recognizes him, and whose death later precipitates his "return" to reality.

The novel does some explaining about the drug KR-3 and how it causes peoples' perceptions of reality to change.

My questions are:

1. Why did Alys taking KR-3 cause Taverner's reality to change? Shouldn't it have changed Alys' perception, not Taverner's?
2. Why did her death bring him back to reality?

Comment: I am tempted to edit the 'philip-k-dick' to add a warning: "Do not ask why or how drugs in his works act like they way. Just accept it".

Comment: @SJuan76 We [don't use](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7924/70236) author tags for questions about specific works.

Comment: @Gallifreyan ok, thank you for telling me.

Comment: @SJuan76 while I agree that philip k dick enjoyed certain "substances" (and it comes through in his works), I'd still like to give him the benefit of the doubt that there was a method to the madness.